# How to show which values of one list are in other list?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Having 2 lists, I want check which values of `List1` are in `List2`. I'm trying as below but I get error

```
List1 = {3,2,8,7,5}
List2 = {1,3,4,2,6,7,9}
= List.Transform(List1, each Text.Contains(List2, _))

Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]
```

My expected output would be `3,2,7`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [List.Intersect Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-intersect)

```
Intersect = List.Intersect({List1,List2})
```

Answer (score 1):

@horseyride has probably the best answer but using your original logic, you could also write the intersection like this:

```
List.Select(List1, each List.Contains(List2, _))
```

This uses `Select` instead of `Transform` since you are trying to select/filter instead of changing the elements and uses the appropriate `List` type instead of `Text` for the `Contains` part.